# Get real resolution on all type of device

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop, resolution

How to get the real resolution on mobile devices with javascript?
The site is running on desktop and mobile.

```
if ($(window).width() >= 640 && isMobile)  // wide screen or android
{
    isSmartphone=true;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can access those properties with

```
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

Or the available width/height (removes unused space, like windows tasksbar):

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

Comment: I already make a test wit this properties.
Is there a way to find not only on PC  browsers but on Mobile also?

Comment: It's supposed to work on mobile too. Sometimes a small delay may be needed to get the correct width/height: set a timeout

Comment: Yes there was a bug where the mobile resolution was empty at page loading, the timeout should fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Blowi and please add comments why you downvote my question?